# How to get rid of Timeout expired waiting for async script on IE11 browser when protractor used

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

Suites running on IE 11 throwing the exception: Failed: Timeout expired waiting for async script. Whereas it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Is it browser specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the timeouts by putting this at the point where you initiate your driver:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: Tried with setting also , we are using protractor

Comment: Generally why we are getting it for IE only

Comment: That is strange. I am using protractor as well and that did the trick for me. Maybe this will help? https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/e34a4abf9957d2aa73e0d8cda262e624ad15e95e

Comment: If I could give you more points I would, thanks for the answer